# Are ios games on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a few questions about ios games. But, I have a feeling that they belong on Ask different. Do they belong here?

ie:

What is the final dragon to unlock on dragonvale?

Comment: Short answer: yes

Comment: There are plenty of questions about iOS games on the site already. The platform doesn't matter, as long as the question is about a game.

Comment: There are also a lot of questions about dragon-vale here already :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the question is about a game, it is probably on topic. Keep in mind that many questions may not fall explictly in the range of a single StackExchange website.

- Server questions about Minecraft could technically be asked on ServerFault.
- Addon questions about World of Warcraft could technically be asked on StackOverflow.
- Questions about the Steam client could technically be asked on SuperUser.

However, because all of these are about gaming, we usually don't close the questions here. Whether or not someone here will have the answer is an entirely different story, though.